# Regex \b with words starting with special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having some difficulties with the regex boundary `\b` character. I need to search for an **exact**  keyword inside some loaded text(either plain textual data or Xml). Because the need for exact matches I use the `\bkeyword\b` pattern but I get a different behaviour than what I expect when the keyword starts with a special character. For example the pattern `\b€ 3,5\b` doesn't match in `I have € 3,5 to spend!`. This is the case with any special characters.

I've search around but came up with no solution. Is there some mechanism that acts like a `\b` but for special characters ? Also note that i cannot alter the keyword.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps make use of a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=^|\s)€ 3,5\b
```

The positive lookbehind will match either the beginning of the string or a `\s`, without including them in the match itself.

Comment: I've adjusted it so it also matches data immediately after the beginning of an xml tag and if the special character is at the end of the keyword `(?<=^|[\s>])€ 3,5(?!\w)`. Works like a charm now, thanks.